# Convert from sql to linq in MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm unable to convert from sql to linq. I have attached my sql query and model with this.

note : we need country and destination start with and country id pass to destination using where condition.

SQL:

```
select Countries.Name,Destinations.DestinationName,Destinations.DestinationID 
from Destinations
join Countries on Destinations.CountryID = Countries.Id 
where
  Countries.Name like '%Sa%' or Destinations.DestinationName like '%sa%'
```

Code:

```
public class Destination
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string DestinationID { get; set; }

        public virtual string DestinationName { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid CountryID { get; set; }

        public virtual string State { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<HotelDetails> HotelDetails { get; set; }
    }

 public class Country : Entity
    {
       //Comment
        public virtual IEnumerable<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }



    }



 var Context = new HotelDbContext();

            var csdf = (from country in Context.Countries.Where(x =>x.Name.StartsWith(desti))
                        from destina in Context.Destinations.Where(x => x.DestinationName.StartsWith(desti))


                        select new
                        {
                            country.Name,
                            destina.DestinationName,
                            destina.DestinationID
                        }
                          );
```

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql to linq would look like this:

```
var csdf = (from d in Context.Destinations
            join c in Context.Countries on d.CountryId equals c.Id
            where
            c.Name.Contains("Sa") && d.DestinationName.Contains("sa")
            select new {
              c.Name,
              d.DestinationName,
              d.DestinationId
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
var result = context.Countries
    .Where
    (
        x=>
        x.Name.Contains('Sa') &&
        x.Destinations.Any(d=>d.DestinationName.Contains('sa'))
    )
    .Select
    (
        x=> new Country
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Destinations = x.Destinations
                .Where(d=>d.DestinationName.Contains('sa'))
                .Select
                (
                    d=>new Destination
                    {
                        Id = d.Id,
                        DestinationID = d.DestinationID ,
                        DestinationName = d.DestinationName ,
                        CountryID = d.CountryID ,
                        State = d.State
                    }
                )
        }
    )
```